# How to edit the styles of the theme?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm using PrestaShop 1.7.2.4.

I disabled Smarty caching. I disabled CSS and JS caching.

But I can not change the classic theme styles. Why?

I go to FTP, edit the theme.css or custom.css file, but nothing happens. Both files are connected in HTML code. If one of these files is removed from the server, it disappears from the HTML code. If these files are not deleted, but their contents are deleted, then files with css code (not empty) are connected on the site.

Why can not I just edit the css code?

Comment: Seems like their is some nefarious magic at play here, "witches", "warlocks" or "sorcerers" ....

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix You summon them with `Ctrl-F5`

Comment: Have you tried to disable the CSS compression (CCC for PrestaShop)?

Comment: @sarcom I wrote everything in the question. Yes, it's disabled.

Answer (score 0):

U should add version control to your modified js or css soemthing like this

```
some.min.css?v=1.1
some.min.js?v=1.1
```

So your browser wont take the cache from its own . :) your browser helps you too to cache files whether your intent or not.

Comment: how about `'some.min.css?s=<?php echo filesize('some.min.css'); ?>'` neat I know...  I used this once on an image editor many moons ago.

Comment: Checking the filesize wont be the best solution. Cause you might have the same filesize even you remove but replace some byte so endpoint it’ll be the same filesize still.

Comment: I think it's not in the browser cache. I'm cleaning the cache. I check the site in different browsers. I even use VPN D:

Comment: @KennethSunday - unlikely.  And it doesn't require manually changing the version every time you make a change.

Comment: I dont say that it will be all the time but can still have a possibilities. So i would rather use another like time() variable but time() always

Comment: Ok, I will one up you `'some.min.css?s=<?php echo hash_file('md5', 'some.min.css'); ?>'`  :-p  I refuse to do manual labor no matter what you say ... ha ha.

Comment: If it wont work that way you should double check wheter your modifying the correct file instead. Cause there’s no way that your browser wont detect if you had change the version of ur css or js using query string

Comment: It's probably being over-written by another CSS file sent after it.  try `!important` and make some obvious change like `background: '#0000ff'`

Comment: PrestaShop has smart caching, but for some reason it does not use my changes in the theme.css file. I'll tell you more. A file with the same name `theme-5e9618.css` is created in the cache directory.  It does not have my changes from the original theme.css file.

Comment: Doesn't sound `smart caching` than.

Comment: `!important` will not help, because my css code just does not appear on the site.

Comment: As I wrote in the question - caching in the CMS is disabled. There is only browser caching. But I clear caches in browsers. I use different browsers to check.

Comment: I have a pure CMS. I open and edit the file /themes/classic/assets/css/theme.css. And in the end nothing changes on the site.

Comment: Try to open the pulled css using your incognito just in case it’ll refresh. To get your updated one

Comment: Sometimes code just do sophisticated magic that every developer be puzzled

Comment: @KennethSunday In one browser the css code was updated. Under the VPN. Why? Why does not the cache clear in either Chrome or Safari? The code has just been updated in Opera under VPN. But the second and subsequent times it is not updated! What is this devilry? D:

Comment: Safari and chrome are both webkit browsers so they behave the same as well. Browser specifically for safari and chrome are doing browser storage to cache same filename so it’ll help the internet users to lessen the bandwidth usage. As i’ve told a while ago the query string on your css or js file can sometimes solve the caching layer of the webkit browsers and to download another file since that’ll be another record for the browser.